# z-index issue on ipad (chrome / safari)

Tags: css, ios, html, z-index

I'm having an issue with z-index in iOS, you can see both images here https://i.stack.imgur.com/s09do.jpg (desktop and iOS).

http://bit.ly/Q47DBP

I have z-index:-11; in my .fondoTop and if I set to a value equal or higher to 0 puts in the back the logo and .redes div. I tried to modify the z-index of .redes and logo div

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your .container_12.

All have z-indexes except that one.
So you could simply add this styles to your .container_12

```
position:relative;
z-index:20;
```

and then you could put a z-index higher than 0 to .fondoTop